# Puppeteer nodejs project keeps freezing

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a nodejs project running puppeteer v13.5.1 which does some webscraping.
After some time (mostly 40-80 minutes) the process freezes without throwing any error. It just stops.

I've added some logs and the strange thing is it happens on different executions.
Sometimes it freezes on

```js
const refreshedHtml = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

sometimes on

```js
await page.click('button.swiper-button-next');
```

I've tried many different variations, last one being:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    devtools: true,
    args: [
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--disable-gpu'
    ]
});
```

Any help appriecated